# Google Analytics - Trying to add user - Getting an error "One of the email addresses entered is the alternative email address of a Google Account..."

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to add a user into Google Analytics properties but whenever I enter the user email address, the form field automatically loads a different email address and also loads an error saying:

"One of the email addresses entered is the alternative email address of a Google Account. The alternative email address has been changed to that account's primary email address."

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why cant i add the user and why am i getting the error message

Comment: Have you checked if the primary account is already added to the View?

Comment: Yes checked... it isn't added in the view